# Find closed-form expression to $f(n)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let ${\mathcal A}_n := \left\{\lceil n/2\rceil, \lceil n/2\rceil+1,\dots, n-1 \right\}$ and

$$f(n) := \begin{cases} \min\limits_{a \in {\mathcal A}_n} \frac 1 4 \binom n a f(a) & \text{if $n\geq 4$}\\ \qquad 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

I am looking for a closed-form expression for $f(n)$, but I could not find it.

---

So far what I have done is to try to get it into Python, I got the first 100 values, and I thought I would be able to guess the closed-form expression, but it is too difficult to guess it.

The first 10 values are:
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
n & f(n) \\
\hline  
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
4 & 1.0 \\
5 & 1.25 \\
6 & 1.875 \\
7 & 3.28125 \\
8 & 6.5625 \\
9 & 14.765625
\end{array}
$$

Putting it in MS Excel I found that it is NOT an exponential expression as I guessed, but I couldn't find any more.

Comment: Your $f(n)$ depends on $f(n)$, so you probably meant for $a$ to range from $n/2$ up to $n-1$, not up to $n$. Did you notice that $f(2n)=f(2n-1)$ for $n\ge4$? (At least, that's true for $4\le n\le 15$. I didn't check further.)  Have you tried looking at the sequence of numerators of the $f(n)$, since the denominators are just powers of $2$.

Comment: It was a typo, I fixed it, thanx! But $\forall n\gneq m>3. f(n)\ne f(m)$ according to my Python program... And yes, even when omitting the $\frac 1 4 $ factor, it is still very hard to guess the genral closed form expression...

Comment: An experimental observation, if this helps - minimum is actually attained on $\lceil n/2\rceil$ for $n\geqslant14$. In particular, this implies that $f(2n)=2f(2n-1)$ for $2n\geqslant16$, and $f(2n+1)=\frac14\binom{2n+1}nf(n+1)$ for $2n+1\geqslant15$

Comment: @DudiFrid  Sorry, my comment had a missing 2. It should say $f(2n)=2\cdot f(2n-1)$. And I just checked this up to $n\approx50$.

Comment: @DudiFrid Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer depends on what I mentioned in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350824/find-closed-form-expression-to-fn#comment879116_350824) — that the minimum is attained on $\lceil n/2\rceil$ for $n>13$; I don't know how to prove it. For $n\geqslant3$,
$$
f(n)=\frac1{3\times4^{\lceil n/2^\ell\rceil+\ell-5/2}}\frac{n!}{\operatorname{rni}(n/2)!\operatorname{rni}(n/4)!\operatorname{rni}(n/8)!\cdots\operatorname{rni}(n/2^\ell)!}
$$
where $\ell=\max(0,\lceil\log_2(n/13)\rceil)$ and [$\operatorname{rni}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Rounding) is the nearest integer to $x$, with the convention $\operatorname{rni}(n+\frac12)=n$ for integer $n$.

Comment: My experiments show that the minimum is unnecessarily attained in $\lceil n/2 \rceil$...:\

Comment: @DudiFrid I meant for $n\geqslant14$, let me add it. Did you find any counterexample? Sometimes it is also attained at $n-1$, but for all $n\geqslant14$ that I checked it is attained at $\lceil n/2\rceil$

Comment: I am now running another kind of check, currently it shows that $f(n)=\frac14\binom n{\lceil\frac n2\rceil}f(\lceil\frac n2\rceil)$ for $14\leqslant n\leqslant7500$

Comment: ...up to 10000 by now